# Unable to rename the resource class name in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, localization, resources, embedded-resource

Unable to rename the resource class name. For the following example (picture below), Resource2 can't be renamed in any way. Either in props, in place in the Solution Explorer or elsewhere.

Could it be a bug in Visual Studio 17.3.5 ?
Please note it seems resources has received some changes between 17.3.4 and 17.3.5.

Anybody has an idea on how to do it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found it. It could only be changes through the "Class View".